# Airflow connection passwords not visible in UI and not connecting to slack when connection saved

Tags: webhooks, slack-api, airflow

So, I'm trying to create a connection between airflow and slack using the SlackWebhookOperator.

Firstly, within the airflow UI, the passwords I'm trying to store do not actually save. Rather than getting ********** in the PW field, I'm not seeing anything at all. This is the first time I'm seeing this and all the connections I had set up before has the password stored.

When I pass the slack webhook directly to the host, my integration runs, so I know it is reaching.

I'm honestly such a novice and I can't seem to find much documentation but I'm concerned that my environment is acting strange. I've tried creating multiple connections and they've all acted this way.

My dag code when trying to call the slack connection:

```
import datetime
from airflow import models
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator   

default_dag_args = {
                    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 9),
                    'depends_on_past': False,  
                    'retries': 1,
                    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
                    }
slack_connection = 'Test'
slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(slack_connection).password

dag = models.DAG(
                'Test_Slack',
                schedule_interval= '@daily',
                default_args=default_dag_args,
                ) 
                
test_send_slack_message = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id = 'Slack_Test',
        http_conn_id = slack_connection,
        token = slack_webhook_token,
        message = 'Test',
        channel = '#channel',
        dag = dag
        
        )
test_send_slack_message.execute(context = None)
```

As I mentioned, the connection does work when I pass in the full slack webhook url.

Comment: Remove the  `test_send_slack_message.execute(context = None)`. Airflow invokes the operator when the scheduler picks it up. What you wrote is to explicitly run the operator before it's ready.

Comment: Cheers for the advice on that. Any ideas why its not picking up my password?

Comment: what airflow version are you running? try adding /editing the connection again it. If this is a bug you will need to report it https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues with reproduce steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by pasting into both the extra field and password field.

Not the best solution but airflow still not showing any sort of password.

Comment: Passwords are not shown in the logs for security reason. All password fields in connections are hidden .

Comment: Yes, I know the text itself would be hidden but airflow has historically shown that there has atleast been text input. In this example, the password value is disappearing completely. I'm also getting a json failure, which would potentially indicate an issue with the storing of passwords.